# Get dynamic input,radio button valus inside tr tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get all the dynamic input box and radio button values inside table tr tag.
i have added tag with same class , but it is not reading all the field , it is reading first set of fields.I want all set of tags values inside js array.

```
var giftDataArr=[];
             giftDataArr.push({
                    pointFrom : $('.st-points').val(),
                    pointTo : $('.ed-points').val(),
                    gift : $('.gift').val(),
                    type : $('input:radio[name=giftType]:checked').val(),
                    comment :$('.comment').val(),
                         });
```

Please check my js fiddle for code.
And also radio button not working properly.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jijeshvu07/7hby04o4/)

Comment: instead of class can you check with different id

Comment: each tr is created dynamically , that's why i used class.

Comment: i think that's the problem you can create the id dynamically with variable.if you need idea for that i will tell you

Comment: did you check my jsfiddle

Comment: As per your question if you want to get all values for each class in array you can use jQuery starts with selector like this   $('[class^="st-points"]')

Comment: have you checked what  $('[class^="st-points"]') returns ?  It will return one object and you can gett all textbox value from that object with each statement

Comment: @Mayur . it is showing all <input.st-points> tags only , not the values. and how to set each values and put that object to array.

Comment: You want to make one json array that will contain all values for all TR line by line right ?

Comment: yah it is showing values,,thnx and in my jsfiddle did you check my  radio button . it is not working properly.

Comment: You have to give different .'NAME' field values for each pair of radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set differnt name for radio buttons of each row. For example `giftType1` for 1st row, `giftType2` for 2nd and so on. To get radio button value use `input:radio:checked` instead of `input:radio[name=giftType]:checked` as the name of radio buttons are different in each row. To get values of all rows iterate through all `tr` and get values from each row and then push them in array like below.

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var giftDataArr = [];
   $('tr').each(function() {
     giftDataArr.push({
       pointFrom: $(this).find('.st-points').val(),
       pointTo: $(this).find('.ed-points').val(),
       gift: $(this).find('.gift').val(),
       type: $(this).find('input:radio:checked').val(),
       comment: $(this).find('.comment').val()
     });
   })
   console.log(giftDataArr);
 });
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/azim101/7hby04o4/3/)